# Why can't I verify user input using javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to verify a user's input on a web login form using JavaScript, but something drives me nuts and I don't know whats wrong. Restrictions: Ref. number must be numeric, and postcode can contain only numbers and letters. So I'm checking this and the length of input fields through out a couple of functions. In addition the HTML form and JavaScript file. EDIT: All validation methods falls, even if i dont enter a value into the fields it redirect me to the succesful login page.

```
<html>
<form method"POST" id="loginform"  action="thank-you.html">
<table>
    <tr>
<td>  Post Code :  <input id="postcode" type="text"  required="required" /></td>
<td>   Ref. Number :<input id="passw" type="password"  required="required" /></td>
<td> <input type="submit" class="submit"value="Submit"  </td>
    </tr>
</table>
</form>
</html
```

And the javascrit code:

```
function formValidation() {
    document.getElementById("loginform").onsubmit = function () {
        var uid = document.loginform.postcode;
        var passid = document.loginform.passw;
        if (postcode_validation(uid, 5, 7)) {
            if (passid_validation(passid, 4, 6)) {
                if (alphanumeric(uid)) {
                    if (allnumeric(passid)) {}
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return false;
}

function userid_validation(uid, mx, my) {
    var uid_len = uid.value.length;
    if (uid_len == 0 || uid_len >= my || uid_len < mx) {
        alert("Postcode should not be empty / length be between " + mx + " to " + my);
        uid.focus();
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}

function passid_validation(passid, mx, my) {
    var passid_len = passid.value.length;
    if (passid_len == 0 || passid_len >= my || passid_len < mx) {
        alert("Password should not be empty / length be between " + mx + " to " + my);
        passid.focus();
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}

function alphanumeric(uid) {
    var letters = /^[0-9a-zA-Z]+$/;
    if (uid.value.match(letters)) {
        return true;
    } else {
        alert('postcode must have alphanumeric characters only');
        uid.focus();
        return false;
    }
}

function allnumeric(passid) {
    var numbers = /^[0-9]+$/;
    if (passid.value.match(numbers)) {
        return true;
    } else {
        alert('REf number must have numeric characters only');
        passid.focus();
        return false;
    }
}
window.onload = function () {
    formValidation();
}
```

Comment: Can you tell us exactly what validation is failing?  Then perhaps reduce the code down to that individual case... even create a jsFiddle?

Comment: " but something drives me nuts and i dont know whats wrong" Well for starters why don't you state what isn't working? What is is not doing that you think it should?

Answer (score 1):

The submit tag isn't closed. Look at the code highlighting Stackoverflow puts there, it's missing on the submit tag.

```
<td> <input type="submit" class="submit"value="Submit"  </td>
```

should be:

```
<td> <input type="submit" class="submit" value="Submit" /></td>
```

Comment: Thank you Tom, i have closed the submit tag, but script still doesnt make any verifications :/

Answer (score 0):

I think you may try to add a final return statement in the innermost if-block.

```
function formValidation() {
    document.getElementById("loginform").onsubmit = function () {
        var uid = document.loginform.postcode;
        var passid = document.loginform.passw;
        if (postcode_validation(uid, 5, 7)) {
            if (passid_validation(passid, 4, 6)) {
                if (alphanumeric(uid)) {
                    if (allnumeric(passid)) {
                        return true;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

I know this seems too simple, but it's obviously missing in your code. 
Without the return statement Javascript defaults to **undefined**, what will prefend your form from submitting.

Comment: Thanks for your efforts but it doesnt seems to work.All validation methods falls, even if i dont enter a value into the fields it redirect me to the succesful login page.

Answer (score 0):

Change your code to the following:

```
<html>
<form method"POST" onSubmit="return formValidation(this)" id="loginform"  action="thank-you.html">
<table>
    <tr>
<td>  Post Code :  <input name="postcode" id="postcode" type="text"  required="required" /></td>
<td>   Ref. Number :<input name="passw" id="passw" type="password"  required="required" /></td>
<td> <input type="submit" class="submit"value="submit">  </td>
</tr>
</table>
</form>
</html>
```

And:

```
function formValidation(theForm) {
    if (postcode_validation(theForm.postcode, 5, 7)) {
        if (passid_validation(theForm.passwd, 4, 6)) {
            if (alphanumeric(this.postcode)) {
                if (allnumeric(theForm.passwd)) {
                    return true;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

This way you don't have to fetch elements by ID, because you have everything you need inside the added parameter theForm. If you don't use the IDs for layout just remove them entirely.

Comment: Thank you Lemmy, this was the solution.I owe u a beer now.Thanks once again.